# How to make a NON-WRITABLE directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security, chmod

Actually i'm aware of a "PHP Web Folder". There seems to be some potentials of incoming attacks. So that i want to make sure this whole directory is READ-ONLY (Only writable by ROOT).

Let's say the directory: `/var/www/html/mywebsite/` (recursively)

Since it is a Web folder, there are users like "apache" and other respective users who owns the files/directories. So regardless of whatever user(s) are inside:

- How do i make that directory only writable by `root` only? **(Not even by Apache)**

Thank you!

Comment: It would have been nice of you if you had first investigated directory permissions before coming to Stack Exchange, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I have the same question. I'm trying to tests my software so that it could not create a file in a specific directory. For that I removed all writing permissions for the directory (chmod 555 dir). To my surprise, the software creates a file in the directory. When I try to create a file manually, linux (correctly) prohibits me from doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "a directory and its users inside".

The root user can always write to any file, so to make a file or directory  writable only to root you make it non-writable by user, group, and others.

Note that the webroot dir is supposed to be writable by the `apache` user, so what you're trying to do is to give it the incorrect permissions. Anyway, the command would be:

```
chmod -R ugo-w /var/www/html/mywebsite/
chown -R root /var/www/html/mywebsite/
```

(this also changes the ownership of the files so the owner does not reactivate writing permissions; thanks to @Fiximan for the suggestion).

This is *how* you do this.  Now, it looks like you have a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If you tell us *why* you want to do this, perhaps we'll be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: to make sure that the user does not reactivate writing permissions, the owner could be set to root in addition. One might double-check the group and group permissions not to run into any problem though.

Comment: Hi @dr01, thanks. And sorry for any confusions. I've slighted updated my question. And also, i want to prevent "apache" also. (Only root to be able to write) Thanks!

Comment: About your edited post: all subdirs should be owned by `apache`.  Which are the names of the other users that own subdirs in the web root?  It looks like there's something wrong in your config.

Comment: Not really something wrong. There are a few number of owners there because of different uploads via FTP. But the brief point is, i just want all the files/directories to be READONLY, and then writable by `root` only. (Can forget about who owns what. Just not to let them WRITE)

Comment: You have different users that upload files via FTP in the WWW directory? Seems not quite right to me. Anyway, I've edited my answer -- that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks @dr01 for the updated answer. I believe this will help (although i've yet to try it). But it's not XY Problem :) I've already mentioned the reason WHY in my question. There is a potential of some attack(s) coming in (with the Shell Execution Scripts UPLOADS) but i can't (at least, do not wish) to shut the sites down. So i just simply want to LOCK DOWN the whole web directory. So my sites will be literally "read only" for the mean time. I hope this explains why its not XY Problem :)